# SAP Web IDE Full-Stack Authorization

Tags: sap, sap-hana

When I change the "configuration type" under Security->Trust in SAP cloud platform subaccount from "default" (accounts.sap.com) to "custom"(SAP successfactors Userstore), WEB IDE doesn't work anymore. It says "You are not authorized to access WebIDE...". How can I have access to WEBIDE again while using custom configuration for Single Sign-on for my custom application that I have deployed in the same account. Can I import WEBIDE roles into successfactors ?

Comment: `while using custom configuration for Single Sign-on` how did you deploy it? Is it SAML or OpenID? Is commercial or trial SCP account? Did you configured trust? Did you assigned WebIDE roles?

Answer (score 0):

I have used automated configuration by using successfactors provisioning, so yes SAML 2.0.

I deployed it from webide from another SCP subaccount that uses default SAP ID service. Yes I have assigned all roles.
But I have assigned the roles to my SUSER, but if I switch to SF for trust/application identity provider, then the user is our company Microsoft AD ID, not SUSER.

Is there a way to give access to everyone for webIDE without restricting.